# Pasting from a certain row

Tags: vba, excel

I want to paste from the row 6.I should import rows from a sheet to another sheet, if only the value of the first cell of each row is X.So, I write this code but it pastes them a the buttom of the sheet. I want that it pastes from the row number 6.  Can someone tell me how to do it ?

```
 lngRow = wksDest.Cells(wksDest.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For i = 2 To wksSrc.Range("A" & wksSrc.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

      If wksSrc.Cells(i, 1) = "X" Then
        wksSrc.Range(wksSrc.Cells(i, 2), wksSrc.Cells(i, 20)).Copy

        wksDest.Range("B" & wksDest.Rows.Count).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
      End If
    Next i
```

Comment: You should give more explanation.

Comment: I should import rows from a sheet to another sheet, if only the value of the first cell of each row is X.So, I write this code but it pastes them a the buttom of the sheet. I want that it pastes from the row number 6.

Comment: FYI it's usually better to add extra details to your original post, rather than as a comment. It makes it easier for other people to understand without having to read all the comments as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the line that is causing the problem:

```
wksDest.Range("B" & wksDest.Rows.Count).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

The part `wksDest.Rows.Count` always returns the number of rows in the worksheet. Looking at your code it looks like `lngRow' is the row number you want to use. So try:

```
wksDest.Range("B" & lngRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```